# accelerator.prepare(model) hangs when Multi-GPUs training on a single machine

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

My simple code hangs when I use accelerator.prepare (model).

```
    acc_test.py:
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    from accelerate import Accelerator

    accelerator = Accelerator()
    model = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, 3, 1, 1)
    accelerator.print("1")
    model = accelerator.prepare(model)
    accelerator.print("2")
```

config :
one machine
4 GPUs (A40)
accelerator config:

- `Accelerate` version: 0.20.3
- Platform: Linux-5.15.0-72-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
- Python version: 3.10.9
- Numpy version: 1.23.5
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 2.0.1 (True)
- PyTorch XPU available: False
- System RAM: 251.54 GB
- GPU type: NVIDIA A40
- `Accelerate` default config:

  - compute_environment: LOCAL_MACHINE
  - distributed_type: MULTI_GPU
  - mixed_precision: no
  - use_cpu: False
  - num_processes: 4
  - machine_rank: 0
  - num_machines: 1
  - gpu_ids: all
  - rdzv_backend: static
  - same_network: True
  - main_training_function: main
  - downcast_bf16: no
  - tpu_use_cluster: False
  - tpu_use_sudo: False
  - tpu_env: []

running command:
accelerate launch  ./acc_test.py

Output:
print ("1").
**accelerator.prepare(model) hangs**
Any help is appreciated.

Any help is appreciated